# Aliases in mysql trigger statements

Tags: mysql, triggers, alias

I am trying to create a trigger using aliases, but I get an error:

```
delimiter |
create trigger death before insert on retiree_hist RH
for each row 
begin 
delete from myjobdata JD
where JD.emplid = RH.emplid; 
end;|
delimiter ;
```

I learned that aliases don't work with triggers. Is there any way around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
delimiter |
create trigger death before insert on retiree_hist
for each row 
begin 
   delete from myjobdata
   where myjobdata.emplid = NEW.emplid; 
end
|
delimiter ;
```

Comment: Still getting an error, it's complaining about the alias for myjobdata